# Which (javascript) environments support ECMAscript 5 strict mode? (aka "use strict")

Tags: javascript, strict, ecma262, ecmascript-5

[ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/drafts/tc39-2009-025.pdf) is in its final draft as I write this; It is due to include a strict mode which will prevent you from assigning to the global object, using eval, and other restrictions. ([John Resig's Article](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) is a good introduction.)

This magical sanity-saving mode is triggered by including the string "use strict" at the top of your file (or function.) However, in older environments, "use strict" is a no-op. If you add "use strict" and don't test it in a strict environment, you could be leaving a time-bomb of not-really-strict code that will break when it really hits a strict environment.

**Which environments actually respect "use strict"?**

Comment: So, I found the tracking bug for Mozilla's implementation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=482298 (That's for SpiderMonkey, I think.)

Comment: Here's the tracking bug for Rhino's ES5: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=489326 and the "Strict mode" bug for Rhino: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=517860

Comment: Looks like this is as close to a tracking bug as we'll get for Webkit/JavaScriptCore: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10701

Comment: More information on ES5 Support (including strict) in SpiderMonkey/Firefox: https://wiki.mozilla.org/JavaScript:SpiderMonkey:PathToFirefox4

Comment: Code lands in Webkit: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/69516

Comment: Firefox and webkit are very close: https://twitpic.com/2xkurz/full (via kangax on twitter)

Comment: Looks like there's a tracking page on the ecma wiki as well: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:es3.1#track_status_of_es5_implementations_in_progress

Comment: Firefox 4 beta 7 has implemented strict mode and is working to some extend.

Comment: Mozilla page on strict mode, with some implementation notes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode

Comment: Chromium http://codereview.chromium.org/6144005/ and v8 http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=919 issue tracking pages.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update**:

See my [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

**Original response**:

None as of now.

Raphael Speyer was [working on Mozilla implementation for Rhino during this summer](http://raphscallion.com/blog/), and afaik, their implementation is pretty close to completion.

I know (based on info from ES-discuss list) that Microsoft is planning to include some of ES5 features into upcoming versions of IE and they might very well be working on strict mode implementation right now (as you probably know, IE8 already includes some of ES5 features, like `Object.defineProperty`).

There's also [Google's Caja project](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) which somewhat emulates behavior of strict mode in some of its variations (Valija, Cajita, etc).

Crockford also recently added this option to [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), but I'm not sure if it actually triggers any additional validations (as per ES5-strict rules).

Comment: Even worse, Speyer ran out of time and didn't implement strict mode, so even though Rhino will support most of the other ES5 features, it doesn't support strict mode. :-(

Answer (score 12):

Now that it's actually released, Firefox 4 is the winner of "first browser to support ES5 Strict Mode." Now you can start using it, as long as you test in Firefox 4.

---

Safari 5.1+ and Chrome 13+ Also support strict mode.

---

The first One is in: [Besen](http://besen.sourceforge.net/). Implemented in Delphi. I think it's stand-alone, but I'm not sure. But it does support strict mode.

Found via [this compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

---

[Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) claims to support ES5 Strict Mode.

Comment: Funny that the compatibility table is maintained by the other poster above.

Comment: Yeah; @kangax is awesome for keeping track of this stuff.

Answer (score 9):

ECMAscript 5 strict mode requires these versions for major browsers (or higher):

**Chrome 13.0

Safari 5.1

Firefox 4.0

Internet Explorer 10.0

Opera 11.6**

No, IE9 does not have strict support, it's new to version 10 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Opera 11.60 already fully supports ECMAScript 5.1 and it's strict mode variation. See @kangax compatibility table.

Comment: Only opera 12, which is not yet released, supports strict mode.

Comment: Nope, Opera 11.60 supports strict mode --> http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-ecmascript-5-1/

Comment: Huh. @kangax's table doesn't cover opera 11.6. Weird.