# Python's __getattr__ in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to simulate Python's `__getattr__` method in Javascript?

I want to intercept 'gets' and 'sets' of Javascript object's properties.

In Python I can write the following:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return key

a = A()
print( a.b )  # Output: b
```

What about Javascript?

Comment: Adding this as comment as question is closed. For js newbies coming from a python background as I am, what I was looking for was, for __getattr__, myObj[myKey], and for __hasattr__, myObj.hasOwnProperty(myKey)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The closest is [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) available in Firefox, which defines a function callback to invoke whenever the specified property is read:

```
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function(){
    return 'foo' // customized user agent
});

navigator.userAgent; // 'foo'
```

It differs from `__getattr__` in that it is called for a known property, rather than as a generic lookup for an unknown property.

Comment: Wow! That's incredible. I wish there was a cross-browser version of this. It would make API programming so incredibly easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Not in standard ECMAScript-262 3rd ed.**

Upcoming 5th edition (currently draft), on the other hand, introduces accessors in object initializers. For example:

```
var o = {
  a:7,
  get b() { return this.a + 1; },
  set c(x) { this.a = x / 2; }
};
```

Similar syntax is already [supported by Javascript 1.8.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Defining_Getters_and_Setters) (as a non-standard extension of course).

Note that there are no "completed" ES5 implementations at the moment (although [some are in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423889/which-javascript-environments-support-ecmascript-5-strict-mode-aka-use-stric/1423951))

Comment: This is not what the original question was asking.