# Is there a javascript equivalent of python's __getattr__ method?

Tags: javascript

In python you can define a object having `__getattr__(self,key)` method to handle all unknown attributes to be solvable in programmatic manner, but in javascript you can only define getters and setters for pre-defined attributes. Is there a generic way of getting the former thing done also in javascript?

Sample code would be smth like:

```
function X() {};
X.prototype={
  __getattr__:function(attrname) {
    return "Value for attribute '"+attrname+"'";
  }
}

x=new X()
alert(x.lskdjoau); // produces message: "Value of attribute 'lskdjoau'"
```

Key point is getting value of attribute programmatically depending on the name of the attribute. Pre-setting attribute does not help because during init there is no information what attributes might be requested.

Comment: Adding this as comment as question is closed. 
For js newbies coming from a python background as I am, what I was looking for was, for `__getattr__`,  `myObj[myKey]`, and for `__hasattr__`, `myObj.hasOwnProperty(myKey)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly the answer is No. See [Python's __getattr__ in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441005/pythons-getattr-in-javascript)

You've got [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter), but as you noted you need to know the name of the attribute you will be accessing.

By the way I think you meant `__getattr__` (`__getitem__` is for things you want to access with `[]`).

Comment: thanks. yes, it would be rather __getattr__

Comment: @Roatin WHY!!!! JS needs this more than any other feature (except the 'less suck' feature that people have been requesting for a decade).

Answer (score 68):

It's now possible if your browser has support for the ES6 Proxy feature. You can check this in the [ECMAScript 6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Proxy).

If you have the proxy support, you would use it as follows:

```js
let handler = {
  get(target, name) {
    return `Value for attribute ${name}`
  }
}

let x = new Proxy({}, handler);
console.log(x.lskdjoau); // produces message: "Value of attribute 'lskdjoau'"
```

Works in chrome, firefox, and node.js. Downsides: doesn't work in IE - freakin IE. Soon.

Comment: Holy crap I've been waiting for this!!!

Comment: Looks like you packaged it. https://github.com/alexmojaki/sorcery#dict_of Nice work!

Comment: Its still not clear to me. Any jsfiddle?