# Log what getter gets using proxy

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I have the following proxy handler that logs get events.

```js
const proxyHandler = {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    console.log("get", prop);
    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
  }
};

const obj = new Proxy(
  {
    value: 4,
    text: "hi",
    get textVal() {
      return this.text.repeat(this.value);
    },
    getTextVal() {
      return this.text.repeat(this.value);
    }
  },
  proxyHandler
);


console.log("------- normal func -------")
console.log(obj.getTextVal());
console.log("------- getter func -------")
console.log(obj.textVal);
```

When I log `console.log(obj.getTextVal())` I get:

```
get getTextVal 
get text 
get value 
hihihihi
```

But when I log the getter `console.log(obj.textVal)`, I only get the following:

```
get textVal 
hihihihi
```

How can I make `obj.textVal` log the `get text` and get `get value` events using proxy? ie. When running `console.log(obj.textVal)` I would like the following result.

```
get getTextVal 
get text 
get value 
hihihihi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer works but there is a bit more elegant solution. You are missing the `receiver` in your Proxy trap and Reflect arguments. Simply change the Proxy to this:

```js
const proxyHandler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    console.log("get", prop);
    return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
  }
};
```

> Notice the new `receiver` in the trap and Reflect arguments.

There is an important distinction between a Proxy trap `target` and `receiver`. In this case, the `target` is the underlying raw object while the `receiver` is the Proxy wrapper. If you do not pass the `receiver` to the Reflect call everything inside the `get` operation will be run against the raw object and won't trigger the Proxy traps.

If you have the time I suggest you read the relevant parts of the ES6 spec to fully grasp the difference between these two. Otherwise, just make sure that you forward **all** Proxy trap args to the matching Reflect call if you are aiming for a transparent wrap.

Comment: Perfect! I must have missed that in the spec, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Proxy` instance to `proxyHandler` object and access the properties through it (instead of `this`).

```js
const proxyHandler = {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    console.log("get", prop);
    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
  }
};
const proxifiedObj = {
    value: 4,
    text: "hi",
    get textVal() {
      return this.proxyInstance.text.repeat(this.proxyInstance.value);
    },
    getTextVal() {
      return this.text.repeat(this.value);
    }
}

obj = proxifiedObj.proxyInstance = new Proxy(proxifiedObj, proxyHandler);



console.log("------- normal func -------")
console.log(obj.getTextVal());
console.log("------- getter func -------")
console.log(obj.textVal);
```

```
console.log(obj.textVal);
```

```
get getTextVal 
get text 
get value 
hihihihi
```

**Update:**

Or you could do the same thing by creating a custom `Proxy` that does the assignment for you
(Note: `Proxy` class cannot be extended but we can use the [constructor return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40714458/1555615) pattern):

```
  class InstanceAwareProxy {
      constructor(proxifiedObject, proxyHandler) {
          return proxifiedObject.proxyInstance 
                 = new Proxy(proxifiedObject, proxyHandler);
      }
  }

  obj = new InstanceAwareProxy(proxifiedObj, proxyHandler);
```

Comment: Oh yes, that does it! A little tricky to wrap your head around but clever!

Comment: Thanks Marinos, turns out there's a super simple way to do this. See Bertalan's answer.

Comment: @RyanKing True. Bertalan's answer is the correct one.