# javascript Proxy of function apply trap gives no access to the receiver Proxy

Tags: javascript, function, apply, es6-proxy

When I have a Proxy the get and set traps both provide access to the underlying target Object as well as the Proxy receiver of the initial access request. This is good, because for some "pseudo properties" of the Proxy that I need, I look up the Proxy on a WeakMap to find an extension object which has such properties that apply to the Proxy but not to the underlying target object.

When the underlying target Object is a Function, then the apply trap will work, but its arguments are only the naked function, and the thisArg and the arguments, not the Proxy receiver of the initial apply. So now my ability to look up extension properties to the Proxy fail.

Is there any other way that I can get back to the Proxy from within the apply trap? Shouldn't that be considered a bug in the Proxy specification? Or at least an inconsistency? If the Proxy is considered useful in get and set traps, why is it not considered useful in the apply trap?

Comment: "*as well as the Proxy receiver*" - no, the proxy is not always the receiver. It might also be an object inheriting from it (when the proxy is used as a prototype), or with `Reflect.get/set`, it might be anything.

Comment: @Bergi, that's interesting and deserves to be featured in the answer. What does it even mean to be a "receiver"? I thought it meant the one who received the get, set, or apply invocation. I thought it isn't even possible to sub-class Proxy, which is why I have this WeakMap from Proxy to additional metadata I want to associate with the Proxy. I would have just subclassed it. Either way, even if I did, I would not get that info in the apply trap, and that's weird. That makes me want to make my own Proxy by somehow Object.create(func) and then override apply (and call?) there.

Comment: I don't mean a subclass of `Proxy`, I mean `const proxy = new Proxy(…); const obj1 = Object.create(proxy), obj2 = Object.create(proxy)`. The "receiver" is the `this` value in setters and getters. In fact, the [apply trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) takes a "receiver" as well, it's called `thisArg` on MDN.

Comment: @Bergi the thisArg in the apply trap is the (Proxy of the) object, not of the function. Apply is trapped only if the function itself is Proxy-ed, and then there is no access to the function-Proxy, only the function.

Comment: Yes, in one case it's the object that a getter/setter is applied on, in the other case it's the object that the method is applied on. (Which could technically be the proxy, if you were doing `fnProxy.call(fnProxy)`, which would be weird though)

Comment: @GuntherSchadow . It's interesting to see how various people run into the same problems with using JS Proxies. I was also about to use WeakMaps to remember supplemental properties, but somehow think there should be a cleaner solution. I guess you have seen the [SO question on extending Proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714787/can-i-extend-proxy-with-an-es2015-class#40714458) . The OP's own answer there might actually be a way to persue. But I'm still wondering why it's not simply allowed by design.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow If you create a new instance of your handler with every Proxy-instance (maybe you don't want that), you could save a reference to the proxy in the handler. Because in all these traps the handler is accessible via `this` and there you could get the proxy.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to first give an answer to the implicit question "Why do some traps have a receiver and others don't?". See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions) for a list of all traps. I was at first missing myself a reference to the receiver within some of these functions. But the logic is as follows: All these traps are interceptors for functions that exist independently from the `Proxy`: the [object internal methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#object_internal_methods) which are invoked whenever an interaction with an object takes place. These internal methods have been made accessible via the [static functions of the namespace `Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect#static_methods). These static functions have the same arguments as those of the proxy handler, yet they are meaningful without a proxy (even though apparently the `Reflect` API was designed having proxies in mind, i.e. making the internal methods available to the proxy). Each of these functions has as many arguments as it needs to perform what it does (without any proxy around). Adding an additional `receiver` argument to [`Reflect.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/apply#syntax) would be meaningless without a proxy around as one already passes a `thisArg` for the function application. On the other hand, [`Reflect.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get#syntax) gets the getter for a property of an object and then applies it - usually with the object itself as `this`, but one might want to replace `this` by any other object (in particular in the case of a prototype chain, where the getter of a prototype is applied to a descendant). Therefore the extra argument `receiver` makes sense even without a proxy around.

And as @Bergi pointed out in the comments, even where present as argument in a trap function, the `receiver` isn't necessarily identical to the proxy anyway, but is simply the `this` of a getter or setter in this context, so can be a prototype descendant of a proxy or even something completely different. To understand the latter, consider the following:
If one calls the `Reflect` functions with a proxy as the `target` argument, this leads to a call of the corresponding trap function with the proxy replaced by the target of the proxy. E.g. the call `Reflect.get(proxy, 'value', exoticObject)` will lead to a call of `handler.get` with `proxy` replaced by the target of the proxy (let's call it `proxyTarget`) but the other arguments unchanged, i.e.: `handler.get(proxyTarget, 'value', exoticObject)`. So in this example, the receiver is not even related to the proxy.

Now for the question how to access the proxy from within the traps: One possibility is to create a specific handler for each proxy and store a reference to the proxy as property of the handler. The handler is always accessible within the traps via "this". So `this.proxy` would give you the proxy within each of the trap functions.

The OPs question mentions also an extension object with supplemental properties and a WeakMap to obtain it. Instead of using the proxy to look up the extension in the WeakMap one could alternatively as well save a reference to the extension in the handler and access it via `this.extension` in the traps.

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide code that takes the suggestion by @Sebastian https://stackoverflow.com/a/74467044/7666635 and shows how I can always have access to the proxy from a closure:

```
function makeProxyFor(object) {
    const proxy = new Proxy(object, {
        get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
            console.log("get", proxy, target, prop, receiver);
            const result = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            if(typeof result == 'function' || typeof result == 'object')
                return makeProxyFor(result);
            else
                return result;
        },
        apply: function proxyGet(func, thisArg, args) {
            console.log("apply", proxy, func, thisArg, args);
            const result = func.apply(thisArg, args);
            if(typeof result == 'function' || typeof result == 'object')
                return makeProxyFor(result);
            else
                return result;
        }
    });
    return proxy;
}
```

Example dialog:

```
> p = makeProxyFor({ x: function() { return { x: 'x'}; } })
< Proxy {x: ƒ}
> p.x().x
+ get Proxy {x: ƒ} {x: ƒ} x Proxy {x: ƒ}
+ apply Proxy {length: 0, name: 'x', arguments: null, caller: null, prototype: {…}} ƒ () { return { x: 'x'}; } Proxy {x: ƒ} []
+ get Proxy {x: 'x'} {x: 'x'} x Proxy {x: 'x'}
< 'x'
```

Comment: Indeed, closure of course also works. I'm glad my answer inspired you. Interesting construction, your iterative proxification, or should one call it "deep proxification"?