# JavaScript array with property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was using array like this

```
var names=['a','b','c'];
```

when I tried to access `names[5]`. it returns undefined simply,gives no error.

After that I changed my array like this

```
var names=[];

for(var i=0;i<inputNumberByUser;i++) //guys my array is populating dynamically,depends upon user input
{
names.push({FirstName:'abc',LastName:'zyx'});
}
```

When I tried below code, it gives me error that, **Could not read FirstName of undefined**

```
names[5].FirstName;
```

why above line is giving error? it should just return undefined as normal array

`names[5]` and `names[5].FirstName` both are not defined. `names[5]` returns `'undefined'` but `names[5].FirstName` error. thats my point. `names[5].FirstName` should also simply return `'undefined'` as `names[5]` did

Comment: in your second case,you are trying to get the value of FirstName from an undefined object.

Comment: Your array contains 3 elements, and you want to access 5th (6th taking in mind that array count starts with 0) element that is not present?

Comment: @Khallister names[5] and names[5].FirstName both are not defined. names[5] returns 'undefined' but names[5].FirstName error. thats my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you are getting error?

Here `names[5]` returns `undefined` and you are trying to access `FirstName` property of undefined element. It's like trying to get address of someone who doesn't exists.

And You also have error in line `for(var i=i<3;i++)` may be you wanted to write `for(var i=0; i<3; i++)`

### Possible Solution

If you are looking to push to `names` array then you should do something like below:

```
var names=[];

// Push objects to names
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i+=1) {
    names[i] = {
        firstName: 'Name: ' + i
    }

    // Lastname defined only for 2 index object
    if (i === 2) {
        names[i].lastName = 'Lastname only on 2';
    }
}


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i+=1) {
    // outputs names[i]
    console.log(names[i]);

    // Check whether lastName property exists on the element or not    
    if (!names[i].hasOwnProperty('lastName')) {
        console.log('no lastName property defined');
    }
}
```

Here we are creating object and assigning to `names[i]`. Remember, `i` is incrementing so each time we'll be assigning objects to new position.

Then in second loop, I am just referencing to those previously assigned values and checking whether they have lastName property defined on them or not.

If you are still confused let us know and we'll try to help you.

Comment: My array is populating dynamically in actual code. I want a workaround if a user tried to access undefined property then just notify, dont give error just like names[5].

Comment: Then you have to check if the property exists or not in the object. Please update your question with this information. Also see [Find javascript object has property or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/how-to-determine-whether-an-object-has-a-given-property-in-javascript) this will give you more concept.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your comment. Please check the answer and let us know whether it works for you or not. If you still feel confused then please update your question accordingly and we'll try to address it.

Comment: I have tried this `names[5].hasOwnProperty('lastName')`.It gives me error that cannot ready property `hasOwnProperty`. its taking that function as property

Comment: how we can test  this for object which does not exist.

Comment: Can you share with us the code that you are using? We'll then be able to share our thoughts with you.

Comment: Thanks @Samundra , I was checking hasownProperty on the Object which does not exist. Now my problem is fixed with it

Answer (score 1):

Because your `for` iteration does not reach the sixth (counting zero) index, but only the third.

What you are doing inside the `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)` is essentially:

```js
names.push({FirstName:'abc',LastName:'zyx'});
names.push({FirstName:'abc',LastName:'zyx'});
names.push({FirstName:'abc',LastName:'zyx'});
```

The result of the iteration would be this:

```js
console.log(names[0].FirstName); // "abc"
console.log(names[1].FirstName); // "abc"
console.log(names[2].FirstName); // "abc"
console.log(names[3].FirstName); // undefined
console.log(names[4].FirstName); // undefined
console.log(names[5].FirstName); // undefined
```

By doing `console.log(names[5])` you are outputting the fifth index's content of the `names` variable. `undefined` in javascript is not necessarily an *error* message.

```js
names[5]
     ^^^ undefined
```

By doing `console.log(names[5].FirstName)` instead, you are trying to access a property of an object that does not exist, since `names[5]` is `undefined`.

```js
names[5].FirstName
     ^^^ undefined
```

Comment: I know that, but im confsuing why it dont gives error on line names[5]? It was also not exist. I want same behavior in names[5].FirstName if it is not defined

Comment: Because by doing `console.log(names[5])` you are outputting the fifth index's content of the `names` variable. `undefined` in javascript is not necessarily an *error* message. By doing `console.log(names[5].FirstName)` instead, you are trying to access a property of an object that does not exist, since `names[5]` is `undefined`.

Comment: yes you got my point, so whats the solution of it. i want `names[5].FirstName` not to give error it should just return undefined

Comment: Then just initialize an empty object in `names[5]` by doing `names[5] = {};`. You can't do that in other ways.

Comment: I have updated my Question,see for loop, now names array length is dependant on userInput. So I cant predefine length

Comment: Try using `try/catch` then like Anurag uses in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2666816/2362433).

Answer (score 0):

Your array has three elements. Your trying to access the sixth element which in your above code will not exist.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, you have created an array having 3 elements i.e `var names=['a','b','c'];` and you are trying to access 6th element from your defined array `names[5]`, which not really exist. Hence it's returning `undefined`.

For the second part of your question you have following codes:

```
var names=[];

for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  names.push({FirstName:'abc',LastName:'zyx'});
}
```

So above piece of codes create names array having 3 element and each one is an object. So you have to access it like `names[0].FirstName`. But you are trying to access `names[5].FirstName`, where 6th elements in names array is not really exist.

Hope this will help you!