# JavaScript's equivalent to PHP's __get() magic method

Tags: php, javascript, properties, get, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript getter for all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties)

Does JavaScript provide a method to access undefined object properties? In PHP the solution is to declare and implement `__get()` method in class.
Solutions using `try { .. } catch { .. }` are not sufficient for me, because I already have very large amount of code which actually needs to stay as-is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript getter for all properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties) - there is not exact equivalent to `__get` but there is `__defineGetter__`.

Comment: @Gordon: *Object.defineProperty()* is the standards compliant method of defining getters now.

Comment: @Haim: That link simply rips off the content at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529496/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-getattr-method  **Always post the SO content link over that other site!**

Comment: @AndyE thanks for the information. You might want to add it as an answer to the linked question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891937/is-it-possible-to-implement-dynamic-getters-setters-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to write a similar functionality and check existing parameters them against the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) array. I'm not 100% that this will solve your problem.