# How can I set a default value for an undefined key in an Observable object without a Proxy?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an observable

```
someObjs$ = this.getData().pipe(
    map((data: Data) => ({
        a: true,
        b: true,
        c: true,
      })
    ),
```

If a flag a user has set somewhere is false, I want to always return to true for a key even if that key doesn't exist once the Observable is unwrapped in the template.

Example,

```
someObj$ | async as obj

{{ obj['d'] }} // true
```

Comment: Not possible without Proxy. JavaScript objects don't have a fallback "all other properties" accessor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529496/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-getattr-method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want **any** key (`obj['foo']`,`obj['bar']`) or predefined keys `obj['d']` but I assume **predefined** keys.

You can use `startWith` operator within the `pipe` method. Create a new `Data` instance and assign `d` property with spread (`...`) operator.

```
const newData = new Data();

someObjs$ = this.getData().pipe(
    startWith({...newData, d: true}),
    map((data: Data) => ({
        a: true,
        b: true,
        c: true,
      })
 )
```

Or in `Data` class, you can assign default values. Then you won't need spread operator. You could just use `startWith` with a default `Data` instance.

Comment: I'm unfortunately looking for a solution for any given key.

Comment: Why do you want such feature? Maybe I can help further if I know the purpose. And maybe you can check if the property exists like "{{ obj['foo'] ? obj['foo']  : DEFAULT_VALUE }}"