# Is there an official implementation of ECMAScript Language Specification?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm interesting in how JS source code works and seems that I should to use [ECMAScript® Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/). In my case I tried to write my own implemetetion of [Function.prototype.call](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.call)

```
Function.prototype._call = function (thisArg = {}, ...arg) {
  // 1. Let func be the this value.
  let func = this
  // 2. If IsCallable(func) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
  if (typeof func !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError(this + "isn't callable")
  }
  // 3. Perform PrepareForTailCall().
  thisArg.func = func
  // 4. Return ? Call(func, thisArg, args).
  return thisArg.func(...arg)
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure that my implementation is correct and would like to compare it with the "official" implementation. Where may I find code references for ECMAScript examples? Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking off-site resources are specifically off topic here. That said, both Firefox and Chrome are open source, so you could look at their source code.

Comment: I don’t see how `thisArg.func = func` achieves PrepareForTailCall().

Comment: Are you earnestly trying to reimplement JavaScript... in JavaScript?

Comment: Actually the `_call` as written has a side effect - making the function being called a property of the `this` value supplied as an argument to `_call`. - which the real `call` method doesn't have. "Abstract operations" can sometimes be implemented in JavaScript and sometimes are only pseudo code that has to be implemented for real in a JavaScript engine.

Comment: Also, by the way, this will throw if `thisArg` is `undefined`.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Does a real ECMAScript implementation exist, or is it just a spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1507848/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reference implementation for ECMAScript, the definitive authoriative source is the specification itself - see also its [Conformance section](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-conformance). It is accompanied by the official [Test262: ECMAScript Test Suite](https://github.com/tc39/test262)

The closest to what you are looking for would be the [Engine 262](https://github.com/engine262/engine262) project.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an official implementation of ECMAScript Language Specification?

Such an implementation is known as a *reference implementation*, rather than an "official" implementation, as surely every conforming and certified <sub>(is that even a thing for ECMAScript?)</sub> implementation is "official".

But **yes**, there is - but as far as I can tell, [only ECMAScript 4 from 2007 has (had?) an actual reference implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20071228103906/https://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2289) which was [available to download from the ECMAScript.org website](https://web.archive.org/web/20071130004209/http://www.ecmascript.org/download.php).

---

[https://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2289](https://web.archive.org/web/20071228103906/https://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2289)

> #### ECMAScript Edition 4 Reference Implementation
>
> The first pre-release of the reference implementation of ECMAScript Edition 4 (a.k.a. JavaScript 2) is now available. We've created [a new web site](https://web.archive.org/web/20071228103906/http://www.ecmascript-lang.org/) for information about the ECMAScript specification and reference implementation. [You can download source and binary forms of the reference implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20071228103906/http://www.ecmascript-lang.org/download.php).

---